# Webdriver: How to override get() method?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

In webdriver, While opening a page

Webdriver.get("www.yahoo.com");

If an element I want to click appears instantly, unnecessarily I have to wait till the page load completes.

Is there any solution/suggestion to overcome this problem?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

In WebDriver there are three implicit waits

1. implicitlyWait

   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
2. pageLoadTimeout

   driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, SECONDS);
3. setScriptTimeout

   driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30,SECONDS);

You can specify the time in above methods to wait before throwing exception.

See this [link](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2013/01/webdriver-waits.html) for more information

Comment: I tried both implicitlyWait and setScriptTimeout methods but none of them allow my page to stop and hand the control back to webdriver. It keeps on loading

Comment: If you want to stop the page loading try this logic driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);

Answer (score 0):

In Default the Web driver instance will wait until the page load completes. But you can change the `timeout` duration using

```
  //Assume driver instance is initialized properly
  driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If the page load exceeds the given duration mean it will throw the `TimeOut Exception`

For more [info](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html).

Comment: Thanks for the information

I have tried the following code.

//Assume driver instance is initialized properly
  driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

But still this doesn't solve my problem. The page keeps on loading eventhough it reaches 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try FluentWait, though this is for handling ajax element but may be useful for your case. here is the resource -
http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/twist/2.3/help/how_do_i_handle_ajax_in_selenium2.html